# How to get sum of columns from razor commands Asp .net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

**This is the model**

> I want to get sum of values in **Mon,Tue,Wed,Thr,Fri,Sat,Sun** and display them on a different page.
> Database is connected with local db using **add migrations** command

```
    namespace TimeSheat.Models
{
    public class Timesheet
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public string Project { get; set; }
        public string Activity { get; set; }
        public string DeptCode { get; set; }
        public int Mon { get; set; }
        public int Tue { get; set; }
        public int Wed { get; set; }
        public int Thr { get; set; }
        public int Fri { get; set; }
        public int Sat { get; set; }
        public int Sun { get; set; }

        public Timesheet()
        {

        }

    }
}
```

**These are some controller methods if needed**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ShowSearch()
        {
            return View(await _context.Timesheet.ToListAsync());
        }

        // GET: Timesheets/ShowSearchResults
        public async Task<IActionResult> ShowSearchResults(string SearchPhrase)
        {
            
            return View("Index", await _context.Timesheet.Where(j => j.Project.Contains(SearchPhrase)).ToListAsync());
        }

        // GET: Timesheets/ShowSummary
        public async Task<IActionResult> ShowSummary()
        {
            return View(await _context.Timesheet.ToListAsync());
        }

        // GET: Timesheets/ShowSummary
        public async Task<IActionResult> ShowSummaryResults(int SearchPhrase)
        {
            var a = View("Index", await _context.Timesheet.Where(j => j.UserID.Equals(SearchPhrase)).ToListAsync());
            return a;
        }
```

Comment: Why don't you make a read-only property on the model that returns the sum of them? public int DaysSum => Mon + Tue + Wed + Thr + Fri + Sat + Sun; You can then use that property wherever you have the model.

Comment: Ah okay thanks, Ill try that. @RyanThomas I am a beginner in this language.

Comment: I want to get a total of individual columns too

Comment: Ah, so you have a List<Timesheet> and want a total of say "Mon"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `@` like below

```
@(item.Mon + item.Tue + item.Wed + item.Thr + item.Fri + item.Sat + item.Sun)
```

Codes of sample view

```
@model IList<TimeSheat.Models.Timesheet>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Summary";
}

<h1>Summary</h1>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Id</td>
            <td>Mon</td>
            <td>Tue</td>
            <td>Wed</td>
            <td>Thr</td>
            <td>Fri</td>
            <td>Sat</td>
            <td>Sun</td>
            <td>
                Total
            </td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model) {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Mon)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Tue)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Wed)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Thr)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Fri)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Sat)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Sun)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @(item.Mon + item.Tue + item.Wed + item.Thr + item.Fri + item.Sat + item.Sun)
                    </td>
                </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Screenshot

[image]